# How to add custom font in PhoneGap

Tags: html, css, xcode, cordova

I am trying to add a custom font to my PhoneGap application and I tried two methods I found on the internet and they don't work using PhoneGap 3 and Xcode 5.

- Using **font-face** method using CSS:

  ```
  @font-face {
             font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
             src: url('fonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf');
           }

  body {
       font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
     }
  ```

  Using Xcode **info.plist** file method:

  1. First I added **DroidKufi-Regular.ttf** in the project resources folder.
  2. Then added a new row in the **info.plist** file called `Fonts provided by application` with item called `DroidKufi-Regular.ttf`. and still doesn't work.
  3. So, in viewDidLoad method I added this line of code `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Arabic Kufi" size:10.0];` but still not working.

Comment: could you solve it at last ?

Answer (score 0):

This works in my app. 'fonts' is a subdirectory in the directory with the css file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'grenouille';
    src: url('fonts/grenouille.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/grenouille.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/grenouille.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/grenouille.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "grenouille";
}
```

I'm not sure that you need all these files, but you can generate them using the site http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

If you still have problems, check letter cases, remove spaces from names and try to apply a preinstalled font family to be sure that your problem is the font and not the css rules.

Comment: it should work with any language. If you have problems with a particular font try using a different one. Sometimes the free fonts you can download from internet have small bugs and the font-generators can't properly convert them.

Comment: i use some standard font, but fonts not applied for arabic and persian test, but changing font for english text by free english font work good,
have you any idea? i really need soled it.

Comment: where i exactly put fonts?
should this (project/www/fonts/customfont.ttf) be ok ?