# Custom Font not working in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, font-size

I have spent 5 hrs tried every solution from all the other threads but still it isnt working.

[Custom Fonts in Android PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454681/custom-fonts-in-android-phonegap)

[Phonegap : Custom font is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588348/phonegap-custom-font-is-not-working)

[How to add custom font in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298128/how-to-add-custom-font-in-phonegap)

All of those above doesnt help. The custom font works on my Browser on my laptop, but when i package it into an App, it doesnt work. Phonegap 3.7, it doesnt work on any devices, but just laptop browser.

```
@font-face {
       font-family:'AppleMyungjo';
 src: url("/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf");
      src:url("/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("truetype");
        }

#open{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:1%;
color:white;
    top:10%;
        font-size: 150%;

font-family: 'AppleMyungjo';
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-shadow: none;

}
```

I checked the log i have an error `file:///font/AppleMyungjo.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

But i do have a folder called font with the ttf inside it.
ttf like this right? [image]

I just tried referencing all these still not working

```
 @font-face {
       font-family:'AppleMyungjo';
 src: url("/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf");
           src:url("/css/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("opentype");
          src:url("/css/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("truetype");
           src:url("../font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("opentype");
          src:url("../font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("truetype");

      src:url("../css/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("opentype");
          src:url("../css/font/AppleMyungjo.ttf") format("truetype");  }
```

Failed to decode downloaded font: 
What should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729035/how-to-embed-font-style-in-android-mobile/23730255#23730255

Comment: Now i have error Failed to decode downloaded font:

Comment: where did you put your font?

Comment: I managed to find out the reason, the tff is for some reason corrupted. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2):

Try this: The problem was with the path it was taking when the font was given through an external css file. To resolve this, declare the font URL inline in the body of index.html

```
<div>
      <style scoped>
        @font-face {
          font-family: Monotype Corsiva;
          src: url('fonts/Monotype_Corsiva.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
      </style>
</div>
```

It worked after declaring the font URL in this manner.